# Is it possible to change the default field separator in awk?

Tags: awk

I'm always using awk to manipulate comma separated files, so the first line in my code is always changing the field separator to "," like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}
$2 < 20 {print $1}' myfile.csv
```

Is it possible to change awk's defaults so that comma is the *default* FS?  It's not a big problem, but it would just make things a bit neater.  I tried googling, but didn't find anything useful; it might be that this isn't possible, but I thought I'd ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: In general, as has been highlighted in the comments, the *safe* way to use an alias is to use a different name, eg `awkc`

Create an alias which sets the Field Seperator to a *comma*.  Put the alias in `~/.bashrc`, or if `~/.bashrc`  sources (includes) `~/.bash_aliases`, then put it there.  You can subsequently override it again in your command to whateveryou like,

Be aware that if you use 'awk' as the name of your alias, your script is totally **not portable**. It will only run properly on a system which has *that particular* alias.

```
alias awkc='awk -F","'
```

Example (using the alias)

```
echo "a,b c" | awkc '{print $1" -- "$2}'
```

Output

```
a -- b c
```

Comment: Aliases such as this one are dangerous. The risk is that someday you will ask yourself: but why the heck is my awk not splitting using spaces ?

Comment: You should name the alias something like `awkc` instead.

Comment: I like the aliasing idea - with @glenn's modification - thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

To change awk default field separator, use the `-F <fs>` option (`fs` being a simple character or a regular expression).

You can also change this `fs` with the awk internal variable `FS`.

Comment: Thanks - I'd forgotten that there was an option for field separator.

Comment: I am just curious if it is possible to change the awk defaults permanently in its config file?